# Pandas name a data frame using string(s)

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I have a string:

```
col_name = 'age'
```

I also have a data frame:

```
result
```

I would like to rename the dataframe as

```
age_data
```

My code is as follows:

```
col_name+'_data' = result
```

However (obviously) this doesn't work. I'm thinking I would have to convert `col_name+'_data'` into a python object (rather than a string) for it to work.

Comment: `result.name = col_name + '_data'`?

Comment: When you say "name" do you mean you want to dynamically create a variable? Why?

Comment: Also, strings *are* Python objects...

Comment: Yes to create a new variable - assume I have a list containing strings and I want to convert them into a variable, as part of a larger solution to a problem.

Comment: I would start by rethinking your solution. You almost *certainly* don't want to use dynamically created variables. Use a container, like a `dict` instead.